# Put directive template as a content of container the directive is attached to

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Normally, when i'm creating a directive, i have two possible ways to deal with directive templates. I can create a html file somewhere on my server and use it's URL in directive settings:

```
@directives.directive "someDirective", [
  '$rootScope'
  ($rootScope) ->

    controller: ($scope) ->

    link: (scope, element, attrs) ->
      return

    restrict: 'A'
    templateUrl: 'path/to/template.html'
    scope: {
      eventId: '@'
    }
]
```

or i can put the script tag somewhere in the markup and use it's ID as a templateUrl:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="template.html">
  <p>Hello {{ name }}</p>
</script>
```

However, i was wondering - is that possible to put that template to directive container tag as a body of it? That's how i want it to look:

```
<div my-ng-directive>
  <p>Hello {{ name }}</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is ng-transclude,

basically ng-transclude allows your to "create" a slot in your original template that will contain the content of the original html element, so in your example a basic directive that does what you want will look like:

```
angular.module('myModule', [])
  .directive('myNgDirective', function() {
    return {
      controller: function($scope) {
         $scope.name = "Test";
      },
      transclude: true,
      restrict: 'A',
      template: '<div><h1>The directive</h1><div ng-transclude></div></div>'
    }
  });
```

This code:

```
<div my-ng-directive>
  <p>Hello {{ name }}</p>
</div>
```

Will return:

```
<div>
  <h1>The directive</h1>
  <div>
     <p>Hello {{ name }}</p>
  </div>
</div>
```